# run local Rscript on remote R server

Tags: r, server

I am trying to run some Rscripts on a remote server which has a fixed IP-Adress.
Background is the following.
I connected a Front-end web app with R and am able to insert different values, which are then passed to R, where different outcomes are evaluated.
Everything works fine when I run it locally. 
I want to be able to run the Web-app from every location, so I set up an RServer with username, password etc.

**What I want to next is to establish a connection between R and the server.**
I wasn't able to find anything on that topic yet, so I hope you can help me with this.

1. Establish a connection to the Rserver with some IP.
2. Login with my username and password
3. Tell my R script where to find the Rscript.exe file

Doing that locally I just tell my php-file:

```
$command = '"C:\Users\Username\Documents\R\R-3.3.1\bin\Rscript.exe" "'.__DIR__.'\rfile.R" '.$json;
```

So I tell him where to find my RScript.exe and to read with that my rfile.R.

Thanks for your help.